# Slow GPU While Training CNN

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, training, pytorch, gpu

**TL:DR**: While training a small CNN on a Tesla T4, the GPU does not run any faster than about 1/3 - 2/3 of its base clock speed. The training time takes forever, and there is lots of weirdness with memory usage (Figure attached below).

I was encountering some pretty strange runtime issues when training a CNN. For reference, I am training it on a T4 in a Google Cloud Platform VM.

My original architecture was (I used a ResNet style architecture with these layers):

[image]

I had been training/testing this with different hyperparameters and whatnot since it only took about 30 minutes to an hour to train. All of a sudden, it began taking extremely long so I reduced the architecture to this:

[image]

I decided to run a profiler on the training loop with only 16 images and these are the results:

[image]

Since `loss.item()` and `test_loss.item()` are only called to gather training and validation statistics, I tried profiling the code without these functions and this happened:

[image]

Overall, the training loop took the same time to run! This was pretty strange to my boss and me, so thought about it a bit more and came to the conclusion that this might be happening because until `loss.item()` is called, there are no functions executed in the graph that PyTorch creates.

Next, I decided to look at the CPU, GPU, and GPU memory usage (using nvtop) to see what was going on during this very long `inputs.to(device)` function call. I did this by incrementing `batch_size` by 1 from 1 to 16 (at `batch_size` 17 I got a memory error). CPU and GPU usage remained fairly similar throughout each of the runs, but memory usage had some very strange behavior.

[image]

As I increased batch size, memory usage increased normally, then drops off around `batch_size` = 7, then increases normally again until we reach a memory error.

Lastly, there is also some weirdness with the GPU itself. The GPU does not run any faster than about 1/3 - 2/3 of its base clock speed while training. **This is probably whats causing the bad performance**, but the cause of the slow clock speeds is still unknown. I know it is not the hardware itself because my coworkers (who have their own Conda/pip environments) use the GPU to train models and have no issues with performance. I changed the CPU on the VM to a newer one with more cores and better single core performance, but I am still experiencing this bad performance.

As of now, I am kind of stumped and don't know what the underlying cause of my slow training and strange memory and GPU usage patterns could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

This is the training loop:

```py
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=100):
    epoch_loss = []
    epoch_acc = []
    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        for phase in ['train', 'test']:

            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()
                running_loss = 0.0

            elif phase == 'test':
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode
                running_test_loss = 0.0

            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                optimizer.zero_grad()

                if phase == 'train':
                    with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase=='train'):
                        outputs = model(inputs)
                        loss = criterion(labels, outputs)
                        # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()
                        # statistics
                        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)

                if phase == 'test':

                    with torch.no_grad():
                        outputs = model(inputs)
                        test_loss = criterion(labels, outputs)
                        running_test_loss += test_loss.item() * inputs.size(0)


            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

        epoch_loss.append(running_loss / dataset_sizes['train'])
        epoch_acc.append(running_test_loss/ dataset_sizes['test'])

        print('Train Loss: {:.4f}\nTest Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch_loss[epoch], epoch_acc[epoch]))

        if epoch % 10==9:
            torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': epoch_loss,
            'acc': epoch_acc
            }, os.getcwd() + '/save_model/{}__.pt'.format(epoch))


    return model, epoch_loss, epoch_acc
```

Comment: How is your CPU and GPU utlization? It may be that your CPU is not able to retrieve the data fast enough for your GPU to process. Also, how large is your dataset?

Comment: @Oxbowerce My CPU utilization is 100% throughout. My GPU utilization reads out as 98-100%, but the clock speed is only up to 2/3 of the base clock. My actual dataset is 10k images that are 300x350, but I profiled the code on a 16 image dataset.

Comment: You can define "inputs = inputs.to(device)" and "labels = labels.to(device)" outside the loop, and pass more argument to the train function like train_inputs, train_labels, etc..